# How can I make shell autocomplete the beginning of a filepath?

Tags: bash, shell, vim, autocomplete, zsh

I have a project with a deeply nested folder structure. Most of the time I know the name of the file I want to work with, but the folder path is too long/complicated to type when I want to edit it, like:

```
vim folder/is/deep/down/there/myfile.js
```

Is there a way to make the shell auto populate the path for me if the filename is unique, with something like:

```
vim *myfile.js
```

press TAB -->

```
vim folder/is/deep/down/there/myfile.js
```

I mostly use bash, but I'm fine with zsh if it can solve the problem.

Comment: This is a question that's probably more appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) then here.

Comment: i create per project variables, ie.`js1=folder/is/deep/down/there`. Then `vim $js1/myfile.js` is not too bad to deal with. I see people spend months jumping thru hoops to get autocomplete to do beyond what it is designed to do. Just MHO. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @shellter, this looks like a good solution if you only have a few paths. But for my project there are tens of deeply nested folders that I want to work with. So giving names to each and remembering them is not a quite feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for, vim will open all instances of myfile.js in the directory. Fish shell will allow me to tab through the different matching files but I'm not sure it that works with bash.

```
vim **/myfile.js
```

Comment: This totally works in zsh too, by default, one don't need a special option. You can execute like that or press Tab which will update the pattern with the list of the corresponding file(s).

Answer (score 0):

What could be a good idea would be to use `locate` utility in a bash script.
Calling your bash script passing filename as argument would be a smart move, and then using the previously named utility to find it.
Having done that you could simply find if there was 1 or more matches, and if there's just a match you can just use `vim [match]`.
And obviously, the script could be called like `./openinvim.sh myfile.js`